# How to show data from ms access according to the ID that is typed in log in

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

Sorry I was not clear enough. I want to show the name of the user when he/she types his/her LRN in the textbox. The name must be shown on another form when the LRN is recognized from ms access.

```vbnet
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Class Class1
    Private Sub GunaButton1_Click(
        sender As Object, e As EventArgs
    ) Handles GunaButton1.Click

        Dim connection
            As New OleDbConnection(
                "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Database4.mdb"
            )

        connection.Open()

        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = 
            New OleDbCommand(
                "select * from Table1 where [Lrn]='" 
                & GunaTextBox1.Text & "'", connection
            )

        Dim loginrd As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        If (loginrd.Read() = True) Then
            Me.Hide()

            With Form16
                .TopLevel = False
                Form5.GunaPanel2.Controls.Add(Form16)
                .BringToFront()
                .Show()

            End With

            MessageBox.Show(
                "Login Successful!", "Login Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK
            )
        Else
            MsgBox(
                "Sorry. The LRN you entered is invalid.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical
            )
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Do you really have forms named `Form16` and `Form5` in your system?

Comment: Where do you want to show the LRN, in Form16?

Comment: What is "the name"? The user name? What form is "another form"?

Comment: Sooo many questions and issues here.  1) Learn to use parameters in your db queries.  2) Don't use a db reader just to see if there are matching records, read up on ExecuteScaler and ExecuteNonQuery(Possible not much use in this context but handy to know).  3) Is there a label (or other control) on Form16 where you've set the access modifier to allow updates from external code? 4)Is Form16 an actual instance of a Form Class? Would also think it is worth you doing research on DataBinding, TableAddapters and MDI Document interfaces

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear enough. I want to show the name of the user when he/she types his/her LRN  in the textbox. The name must be shown on another form when the LRN is recognized from ms access.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you're trying to do, but i think your problem is how to pass data from one form to another. If that is the case  just see this example.

Do it like this, create 2 forms with the names: FormLogin and FormAfterLogin. In FormLogin put a button and in FormAfterLogin put a textbox.

Double click the button in FormLogin and write this code:

```
Sub Button1_Click (......)
    FormAfterLogin.LoadForm ("this is the data that i want to pass.")
    Me.Close
End sub
```

In FormAfterLogin insert this code:

```
Sub LoadForm (sName as string)
    textbox1.text=sName
    me.show
End Sub
```